# How can I read the size in bytes of a serialized object in Java?

Tags: java, object, serialization, size

Is there a way of reading the total used size of a serialized object from stream before or after deserializing it?

The only way I could find was to serialize it again into a byte buffer and see that buffer total occupied size. This works, but it seems to be a waste of resources.

Edit: I'm not interested in the space that the Object instance uses while loaded in memory. Only the serialized size in bytes.

Comment: What about java.lang.instrumentation.getObjectSize(o)?

Comment: Why? You don't need it to do the deserialization, and you don't need it afterwards as you have the entire object. What's the purpose here?

Comment: The purpose is to implement a specialized transport protocol which can talk to other Java and non-java clients. I've just implemented that way: serializing the whole object to memory and then counting the bytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to determine the size before deserialization, because the serialization protocol doesn't waste the time pre-computing the size of output; it simply processes objects until it's done.

To read the size after deserialization, you can insert a [CountingInputStream](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/input/CountingInputStream.html) between your `ObjectInputStream` and the underlying stream.

Edit: if you absolutely need to determine the size pre-serialization, then I suppose you could serialize to a `ByteArrayOutputStream`, and write the resulting bytes to the output. But that would require both sender and receiver to agree on how to handle the bytes.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I thought that somewhere in the serialized header there could be a field with the size. Or maybe a method hidden somewhere in the API.

Answer (score -1):

The serialized size is the sum of all of it's fields, and itself. I'm assuming you've got a good way to check the size of the Object, so check the size of the Object, and then add to that all of it's fields.

Comment: I don't have that good way. The only way I know of is to serialize the Object to a buffer and count the resulting size afterwards. What i want to know is if I can get the number without having to waste resources simply writing an object to a buffer in order to count its size.

Comment: The serialized size is the sum of the field value sizes, plus padding, plus the class descriptor, plus value tags, plus object handles, minus the effect of handles for member objects that have already been serialized, plus all that for serializable base classes, plus whatever else was put in there by custom writeObject() or writeExternal() methods anywhere in the parent class chain, as modified by whatever custom writeReplace() methods may have done. -1.

Comment: @EJP "padding" not really the size of the class, granted it takes up that space, but I'm talkin class size.. "class descriptor, plus value tags, plus object handles, minus the effect of handles for member objects that have already been serialized, plus all that for serializable base classes, plus whatever else was put in there by custom writeObject() or writeExternal() methods anywhere in the parent class chain, as modified by whatever custom writeReplace() methods may have don" this all falls under class. That was a crappy -1... If you could -1 comments, I would